# Can't See Launcher and settings in 11.10

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. From past few days, when i choose standard ubuntu interface at startup, i cannot see Launcher and settings in upper right corner. I can just see desktop folders and File, Edit, View, Go,etc. 
I can use unity without any problem in Ubuntu 2D interface.
Please Help me.

Comment: can you tell us which graphic card you are using and which drivers for it you have installed? maybe unity 3D does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the unity plugin isn't enabled anymore, so you need to check & enable it if it isn't

This needs to be done while in the ubuntu (unity 3d) session, there are numerous ways to do this, picking one -

Log in to ubuntu and go Ctrl+Alt+t on the keyboard, if a terminal opens great.

If a terminal doesn't open, then up in that top panel click on "Go". In the nautilus window, on left side in Computer section click File System & then browse to usr > share > applications. Scroll down & d. click on the terminal icon

If you don't know if compiz-config-settings-manager is installed then run this in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-config-settings-manager
```

Once it's installed or if it already was then run this

```
ccsm
```

scroll down & enable the unity plugin if it isn't enabled

P:S.: If CCSM is installed, it works in Unity 2D sessions as well.